# The vespa returns an error when I put one document with documentAPI

Tags: vespa

I build vespa, and install it on physical machine, call `/opt/vespa/bin/vespa-start-configserver` and `/opt/vespa/bin/vespa-start-services` .
I submit my application package normally, and `http://localhost:19071/application/v2/tenant/ourtenant/application/` works fine.
But when I feed it with one document, it failed:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data-binary @/opt/samples/bd-search-data/english1.json
http://localhost:8080/document/v1/mynamespace/kosmos/docid/1
response:
{"errors":[{"description":"DOCUMENT_EXCEPTION [ENCODE_ERROR @ localhost]: Protocol 'document' failed to encode message. ","id":-11}],"id":"id:mynamespace:kosmos::1","pathId":"/document/v1/mynamespace/kosmos/docid/1"}
```

Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: I asked for more information in https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/15136